# How to load an image to an object

Tags: java, image, object, rendering

I have got an object class and inside this class I have a render method. I would like to know how I can render an image.

I have searched the net but it is all so vague, I am quite new to coding so that is why I end up asking.

Comment: please include more context and/or code. Are you using a JFrame or something else? [Here](https://github.com/Dando18/DataDisplay/blob/master/src/com/datadisplay/ImageView.java) is some code I've written before that might give you a hint.

Comment: Can you point us to the tutorial you are following?, and next time it is better if you ask for "the ambiguous parts" of such tutorial rather than *How to do X?* if it is vague in the tutorial most surely our answers will be as ambiguous too; also it is not beneficial for other members in the community since it is a very specific question, always try go go generic when you ask and go specific in the comments. **Wellcome to the comunity @Karl** (I advice you [this reading](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JFrame add this JPanel to your frame:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageView extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Image img;

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int width = this.getWidth();
    private int height = this.getHeight();

    public ImageView(){
        super();

        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("<img_path>.jpg"));
        }catch(IOException ex){
            // catch exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        if(img!=null){
            g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, this);
        }
    }

    // your render method
    public void render(Image img){
        this.img = img;
        repaint();
    }

}
```